# Error al calcular distancia recorrida acumulada en android

Tags: android, gps

Hago el calculo dentro de un thread

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                Coordenada coordenada  =getLocation();

                Location locationA = new Location("point A");

                locationA.setLatitude(lat);
                locationA.setLongitude(longi);
                Location locationB = new Location("point B");

                locationB.setLatitude(coordenada.getLat());
                locationB.setLongitude(coordenada.getLongg());

                distancia = distancia + (locationA.distanceTo(locationB));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

getLocation() es un método que me devuelve latitud y longitud, eso funciona correctamente, el thread lo lanzo con un botón y lo detengo con otro pero el resultado obtenido en distancia es 0.0.

Cual puede ser el error ?

Comment: ¿Te estas moviendo?

Comment: Si. bastante, en vehículo, como 3 km. Y lo probé sobre el dispositivo, no en emulador.

Comment: Solo quería confirmar, jaja, estoy investigando un poco

Comment: Ya viste que tienes `getLat` y `getLongg` en lugar de `getLatitude` y `getLongitude`, revisa este hilo, espero que te funcione , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android